# Include Tags in Review Revision Tab

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

Hopefully a simple request.  Would it be possible to put the Tags associated with a question on the Revision tab (as well on the Question tab) for Reviews?

Often times, the question is "so far gone" that it doesn't matter, but for borderline questions, or for better context, sometimes just having the tag there would be helpful.

Comment: Which review queue are you asking about? All of the queues I can see right now have the tag(s) on them...

Comment: Specifically, it was the Reopen queue.  It is available in the Question tab, but I didn't see it in the Revision tab.  And now I have to wait 4 hours to see it again.  :)